# Why does pointer subtraction yield a number unrelated to the values pointed to?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int arr[] = {10,20,30,40};
    int *p1 = arr;
    int *p2 = &arr[2];

    printf("%d",p2-p1);
}
```

Output : 2

I was suprised to see the output as 2. I don't know why the output is 2.

Comment: Because that's the way pointer arithmetic works. The difference is 2 elements (not bytes).

Comment: Aside: take notice of compiler warnings – `%d` is the incorrect format specifier.

Comment: What *did* you expect to see? 8 (the distance in bytes) or 20 (the difference in the elements' values)?

Comment: Please try to write your questions so they're going to be useful to more people than you. The next person to have a program using pointers with an unexpected output of 2 is likely to have a _completely different_ underlying problem leading to that unexpected output, so the title that's currently written isn't helpful to let other people with the same technical question find answers that will help them.

Comment: (I edited in a title that better describes the technical question as opposed to the circumstance it was found in, but there's some guesswork; If you'd answered Weather Vane's question about what output you _expect_, it would be easier to be confident in that title).

Comment: Valid pointer values are *addresses* of objects or functions.  These are in a whole other type category from the pointed-to objects or functions themselves.  Object pointers provide *access to* their pointed-to objects, but they are not *aliases for* those objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[] = {10,20,30,40};


arr     | 10  | 20  | 30  | 40
index   |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3
pointer | @+0 | @+1 | @+2 | @+3

int *p1 = arr;
int *p2 = &arr[2];
```

this mean, p1 points to the first address of the arr which is @ and p2 points to the third element of arr which is @+2

```
printf("%d",p2-p1);
```

p2-p1 => @+2 - @ = 2
so output is 2

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
int *p1 = arr;
```

the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. It is equivalent to the following declatayion

```
int *p1 = &arr[0];
```

An expression like that `arr[i]` where `i` is some integer is evaluated like `*( arr + i )`. That is the expession `a[0]` is evaluated like `*( a + 0 )` that is the same as `*( a )` or `*a`. And the expression `a[2]` is evaluated like `*( a + 2 )`. Applying the address of operator for the expressions you will get that the valie of `p1` is equal to `a + 0` or `a` and the value of `p2` is equal to the value of the expression `a + 2`.

So the difference `p2 - p1` is the same as `( a + 2 ) - a` that is equal to `2`.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

8 When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the
array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
**In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th
and i − n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist.** Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point
to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past
the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

Pay attention to that the type of the expression is `ptrdiff_t`. So you should write

```
printf("%td",p2-p1);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d",p2-p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract `p1` from `p2` i.e. `(p2 - p1)`, you're essentially finding the difference between their memory addresses. Since both pointers are pointing to elements within the same array, the difference between their addresses indicates how many elements apart they are in the array. So, `p2 - p1` gives you 2, indicating that there are 2 integers (or elements, each element is of 4 bytes because of `int`).

If you intend to access the value, you can do it by `printf("%d",*p2-*p1);`

Comment: Regarding "*Since both pointers are pointing to elements within the same array*", note well that both pointers pointing either to elements of the same array or just past the end of that array is a condition for the pointer difference to be defined by the language spec at all.  To the extent that this answer suggests that pointer difference operations are more general than that, it is misleading.